# ColdFusion: When to define session variables?

Tags: session, coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-9

When a user requests a page, is this when a session is started for that user? From what I can tell, a session is started as soon as you make a page request...

If this is the case, when do you create session variables? i.e. username, password, preferences, etc... just any time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the session scope for the user is setup on the first request. However it depends on your preference as to when you want to set various flags and values. You probably don't want to put password in the session scope though.

What I like to do is put user specific values in a user struct. So on request start I'd check for the variable and setup if it doesn't exist. For example...

```
<cfif not structkeyexists(session, "user")>
    <cfset session.user = {
        authorized = false
        , admin = false
        , username = ''
        , accountid = ''
        <!--- etc --->
    } />
</cfif>
```

When the user logs in you can then fill in the appropriate values and set session.user.authorized = true

When the user logs out the nice thing about this approach is you can just delete the users struct.

```
<cfset structdelete(session, "user") />
```

Then on the next page the check will be made again for the user struct and created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, I like this approach quite a bit, Dan. In PHP, the session doesn't start until you specifically tell it to start. That's where my confusion came in. But why not put the struct creation within the application start or session start?

Comment: The idea here is that a session could technically be shared by multiple persons. If one person sits down at a browser, uses it, logs in, logs out, etc... then another person sits down and starts using it in ColdFusion that is all under the same session. OnSessionStart would only occur once in that situation not twice. So you want the user struct to be recreated if it doesn't exist regardless of whether the over arching session is being started.

Answer (score 5):

The basics of configuring and using session variables are [explained here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html).

A session is basically a logical relationship between a client and an application, so session variables are available from the client's first request to your application, and the session is typically persisted across requests using cookies which uniquely identify the session, although this can be also done by passing the identifiers in the url. It's worth paying attention to your session timeout settings, for example you may want to provide a shorter timeout to bots/crawlers which don't set cookies and will therefore initiate a new session for each page request ([more details on this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1083-ColdFusion-Session-Management-And-Spiders-Bots.htm)).